# cURL Simple File Upload - 417 Expectation Failed

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I have a problem with a simple file upload post with cURL... 
I did it so many times but in this case I always get "417 Expectation Failed" from server.
When I try to post with my browser it works 100% but with cURL not.

That's my configuration:

My simple test form that works:

```
<form action="http://images.example.com/image_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="50">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

here the image_upload.php:

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/images.example.com/images/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Upload failed";
    }
?>
```

my cURL script (image_upload.sh) looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

file=$1

result=$(curl -s -L -F "userfile=@$file;type=application/octet-stream;" "http://images.example.com/image_upload.php")

echo $result
```

and here the server headers:

```
> POST /image_upload.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.18.2 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.18.2 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.1.4 libidn/1.8 libssh2/0.18
> Host: images.example.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 579
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------e237975526cf
>
< HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 02 Feb 2012 21:29:22 GMT
< Server: lighttpd/1.4.19
```

I don't know where the error is, maybe you can recognize it.

Comment: Can you show us the body of function `move_uploaded_file`.

Comment: the **move_uploaded_file** ist php build in function see: [link](http://php.net/manual/de/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i get the same result. :( Its little bit strange, via WebForm works but not with cURL...

Comment: **[SOLVED]:** by adding _-H "Expect:"_ to cURL Headers will solve this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can also be fixed using set opt header setting:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:  "));
```

http://www.khattam.info/417-expectation-failed-in-php-curl-while-submitting-multi-part-forms-2011-04-14.html

Comment: c# WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("Expect", ""); failed.

    client.Headers.Add("Expect", "*"); worked

Comment: The above solution is for PHP

Comment: still works after 5 years, but I'm always a little bit uncomfortable with such solutions where I don't understand _why_ they are working...

Comment: I think I found out why it works, so for anyone curious: apparently for data > 1024 bytes CURL automatically sets "Expect: 100-continue" (the client expects the server to only fetch the header and then send a "100" return code to get the rest of the data). If the server can't be bothered, CURL produces this error. Setting "Expect: " explicitly disables this automatic behaviour.

Answer (score 21):

This happens when you are behind a proxy which is running in HTTP 1.1 mode where as the client is running in HTTP 1.0. In curl command line you can add `--http1.0` in the arguments to solve the issue

Answer (score 21):

add this to your lighttpd config:
    server.reject-expect-100-with-417 = "disable"

restart lighttpd. cheers :)