# curl HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed

Tags: php, curl, vbulletin

Im having problem with curl and 417

im passing long value around 800 chars by POST

ok and the only solution ive found is:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:' ) );

it would be great if it didnt cut my string exacly at 100 (or simillar to this)
and it sends only 100 chars from my string

how to fix it?

additional info, server on: vBulletin and lighttpd/1.4.35

Comment: sorry but ive just found out it cuts on special chars my string

Comment: ok found out ERROR, this question might be closed now
page charset to utf-8 changed and now it works perfectly :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL Simple File Upload - 417 Expectation Failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120760/curl-simple-file-upload-417-expectation-failed)