# passing curl file as $_FILES['htmlfile'] with temp_name

Tags: php, curl

I have a listener script to which i want to upload a file using CURL(not the command line version) however, it is not getting recognised as  $_FILES['htmlfile']. other post vars are also required on the server. How can i solve such an error?

After some changes to my script, i get the 417 - Expectation Failed message. Any ideas?

Comment: May be this will help you  http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/sending-files-using-curl/

Comment: i now have this: 417 - Expectation Failed

Comment: the pfsense server is expecting: multipart/form-data
if i curl to localhost, the values are correct. But pfsense throws 417 status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your curl request. It will prevent 417 error.

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:  "));
```

Other possible solutions:
[cURL Simple File Upload - 417 Expectation Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120760/curl-simple-file-upload-417-expectation-failed)

It's important to know that you are "overwriting" error. It's something like fix but usually is okey. 417 is typical error when you have request between http1.0 and http1.1.

Comment: You sir, are my hero! <3