# PHP, cURL, REST-API - PUT a variable with many values into JSON array

Tags: php, json, api, curl, put

with the following code

```
<?php
                //PHP Infos anzeigen lassen
            //phpinfo();
          header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
            // Inhaltstyp und Zeichenkodierung für Skript festlegen
                $User_Agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0';

            $id = $_POST["id"];             
                // Übernahme Formulareingabe
                $url = "http://hub.culturegraph.org/entityfacts/$id";
                // URL festlegen

                $request_headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
              $request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8';
              $request_headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate, identity';
              $request_headers[] = 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3';
              $request_headers[] = 'X-picturemaxx-api-key: key';
                $request_headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer token";
            // Optionale Anfrageoptimierungen

              $ch = curl_init($url);
              //  Initiate curl
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $User_Agent);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
                // Anfrage optimieren
                // Execute
                $result = curl_exec($ch); // Performs the Request, with specified curl_setopt() options (if any).
        curl_close($ch);
        // Closing

        $data = json_decode($result, true); // Dekodiert eine JSON-Zeichenkette, Übergibt an Variable
        foreach($data['variantName'] as $alternativ) {
        echo $alternativ . " ; ";

}
```

i receive json-data. The output from the variable $alternativ looks like

"Johann Wolfgang Goethe ; Johan Wolfgang von Goethe ; Johan Wolphgang Goethe ; Johan W. von Goethe ; Joh. Wolfg. v. Goethe ; J. Wolfgang Goethe ; J. W. v. Goethe ; J. W. Goethe ; Jan Wolfgang Goethe ; Jean Wolfgang von Goethe ; Juan Wolfgang von Goethe ; Juan Wolfgang Goethe ; Juan W. Goethe ; João Wolfgang von Goethe ; Iohann Wolfgang Goethe ; Iohan Wolphgang Goethe ; Ioannes W. Goethe ; I. W. Goethe ; Wolfgango Goethe ; Wolfango Goethe ; W. von Goethe ; Volfgango Goethe ; Volfango Goethe ; Giov. L. Goethe ; G. L. Goethe ; Goethe ;

and so on.

Next i try is to PUT the values of the variable $alternativ into the json-array/database field 'classification_element_name'

```
$url2 = "https://bpk.bs.picturemaxx.com/api/v1/editing/classifications/42/elements/2156013";



$dataj = array (
  'classification_element_parent_id' => 0,
  'classification_element_matchcode' => '',
  'classification_element_foreignref' => '',
  'localized' => 
  array (
    'en-us' => 
    array (
      'classification_element_name' => '',
    ),
    'de-de' => 
    array (
      'classification_element_name' => $alternativ,
    ),
  ),
);

        $data_json = json_encode($dataj);

              $ch = curl_init($url2);
              // Set the url
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $User_Agent);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);

                // Execute
                $result2 = curl_exec($ch); // Performs the Request, with specified curl_setopt() options (if any).
                $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                // Closing
        curl_close($ch);
```

This works. But only one respectively the last value of the originally many values from the variable $alternativ appears in the database field. How do I change the code so that all values of the variable $alternativ are transferred into the database field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just loop & echo the elements and dont assign them to a variable

```
foreach($data['variantName'] as $alternativ) {
    echo $alternativ . " ; ";
}
```

$alternativ will allways be the last element of $data['variantName']. 
You need to replace $alternativ with $data['variantName'] in your $dataj array or
assign a new Variable and use this in your $dataj array

eg:

```
$alternativData = array();
foreach($data['variantName'] as $alternativ) {
    echo $alternativ . " ; ";
    $alternativData[] = $alternativ;
}

$dataj = array (
  'classification_element_parent_id' => 0,
  'classification_element_matchcode' => '',
  'classification_element_foreignref' => '',
  'localized' => 
  array (
    'en-us' => 
    array (
      'classification_element_name' => '',
    ),
    'de-de' => 
    array (
      'classification_element_name' => $alternativData,
    ),
  ),
);
```

or if it should look like 'data1;data2;data3..'
them use:

```
$alternativData = array();
foreach($data['variantName'] as $alternativ) {
    echo $alternativ . " ; ";
    $alternativData[] = $alternativ;
}

$dataj = array (
  'classification_element_parent_id' => 0,
  'classification_element_matchcode' => '',
  'classification_element_foreignref' => '',
  'localized' => 
  array (
    'en-us' => 
    array (
      'classification_element_name' => '',
    ),
    'de-de' => 
    array (
      'classification_element_name' => implode(';', $alternativData),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hello PHPunk. Sorry that does not work. For the first solution all i get is "Array" in the database field. And for the second idea i get nothing.

Comment: oh i have a type, sorry. i, will edit the code again.

Comment: try again please :)

Comment: I have already noticed the spelling mistake and corrected it. After that I only get an empty database field. no values are taken over.

Comment: can you do a print_r( $alternativData ); and a print_r( $dataj ); and post it?

Comment: print_r( $alternativData ); returns: Array
(
    [0] => Johann Wolfgang Goethe
    [1] => Johan Wolfgang von Goethe
    [2] => Johan Wolphgang Goethe
    [3] => Johan W. von Goethe
    [4] => Joh. Wolfg. v. Goethe
    [5] => J. Wolfgang Goethe
    [6] => J. W. v. Goethe
    [7] => J. W. Goethe
    [8] => Jan Wolfgang Goethe
    [9] => Jean Wolfgang von Goethe
    [10] => Juan Wolfgang von Goethe
    [11] => Juan Wolfgang Goethe
    [12] => Juan W. Goethe

Comment: print_r( $dataj ); returns: Array
(
    [classification_element_parent_id] => 0
    [classification_element_matchcode] => 
    [classification_element_foreignref] => 
    [localized] => Array
        (
            [en-us] => Array
                (
                    [classification_element_name] => 
                )

            [de-de] => Array
                (
                    [classification_element_name] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Johann Wolfgang Goethe

Comment: ok this is correct, all values are in dataj/alternativeData. Please try tu use implode(' ', $alternativData) instead of implode(';', $alternativData)

Comment: unfortunately not working either. empty database field again

Comment: does it work if you set the value manuel to "Johann Wolfgang Goethe ; Johan Wolfgang von Goethe " ? could it be that there is a max input lenght ? If there is something like 'Göthe' or 'J. Wolfgang göthe' you should try to utf8_decode/Encode your string .

Comment: When i set the value manuel in the 'classification_element_name' field then it works. i thought with the header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); the is string already utf-8?

Comment: the header command just sets the header for your browser not for curl, but you have curl headers set (your $request_headers). Please give it a try and test if a part of the complete string would work [eg: 'classification_element_name' => substr(implode(' ', $alternativData),0 ,20) ], and/or if utf8_decode/encode works :)

Comment: now the first 20 characters of the string have been correctly entered into the database.

Comment: When i set substr(implode(' ; ', $alternativData),0 ,200) it works. But when i set substr(implode(' ; ', $alternativData),0 ,2000) it does not work.

Comment: how do i have to add utf8_decode/encode to substr(implode(' ; ', $alternativData),0 ,2000)?

Comment: I can do that till substr(implode(' ; ', $alternativData),0 ,765). after that it does not work anymore. why that? is the database field perhaps limited to this number of characters?

Comment: hi again, there are two possible problems. first one: character limit of db field (765 would be a strange limit). second one: wrong encoding. try utf8_decode(implode(';', $alternativeData)) or utf8_encode(implode(';', $alternativeData));

Comment: hello. sorry but that doesn't work either. even if i give the numbers to it again. also if i try to print the characters from substr(implode(' ; ', $alternativData),765 ,800) the database field remains empty. so far only substr(implode(' ; ', $alternativData),0 ,765) really works.

Comment: Ok i found the problem. I forgot to set the header "'Expect: ';" and "'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json)".   Explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120760/curl-simple-file-upload-417-expectation-failed. So the version with "'classification_element_name' => substr(implode(' ; ', $alternativData),0 ,10000)," works!